# Excel merge two lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel lists:

1. One extensive with 20 thousand lines. In which:

Two columns are important: First: Unique ID, Second: a value (number formatted).

It can be a value that appears several times, or only once.

2. I have to create the second list. In this list I have only one column of values that I would like to have.

I need a formula that will look for values from List 2 in List 1 and then match a Unique ID to each value.

It is important that, when no direct value exist. In this case it has to search for a sample which is in about 3-5% value deviation.

Example: there was no value 127, but within 3%, 125 was found.

I've tried indexing and comparison, but it does not seem to work.

VLOOKUP worked, but without 3-5% deviation

I am very grateful for the help.

Example: http://www.filedropper.com/excellist1and2

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,D1:E6,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I uploaded both files.

Comment: @D_Bester    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,D1:E6,2,FALSE),"") i tried it, VLOOKUP works only with exact results. I tried to use whole sentence so: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,D1:E6,2,FALSE);VLOOKUP(AREAs(F1:G1,D1:E6,2,FALSE))  Where F1:G1 are those deviations from:to. Don't workd-bester

Comment: `VLOOKUP(B1, D1:E6, 2, TRUE)` will be a Range Lookup, but finds the next lowest value, not the nearest or highest

Comment: i need it to work with ranges: ex. no result with 100, 3% deviation Range from 97 to 103. I need to search in that spec. Range. If result is not found, i can't use it in my 2nd list. In my 1st list are gaps. 100, 120, 200, 400. So if he finds lowest result, it won't be match for my list. I can't use  200 instead of 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value exists in the list, you can use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX(MATCH` to find it - that's the easy part.  If the value is *not* in the list, then you need to find the nearest value.

The nearest "low" value will be the `MAX` value ≤ our input, and the nearest "high" value will be the `MIN` value ≥ our input.

If you have Office 365, you can use `MINIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,">="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&(B1*1.05))` and `MAXIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,">="&(B1*0.95))` )` here.  If not, you'll need an Array Formula, we can build that "±5%" in early, to simplify the formula.

Starting with the Low values, we want the `MAX` value ≤ our input **and** ≥ 95% of our input.  Putting an Array Formula in a `SUMPRODUCT` so that we can use it in a normal formula, we get `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$1:$D$6>=(B1*0.95))))`

The High values are slightly harder, because we can't just multiply be 0 to cancel out anything too low, or over 105% of the target.  We need to add a huge number like `1E+99` (a 1 with ninty-nine 0s after it) instead, so that the `MIN` will ignore them: `SUMPRODUCT(MIN($D$1:$D$6+1E+99*(--($D$1:$D$6<B1)+--($D$1:$D$6>(B1*1.05)))))`

The last steps are to decide which of these numbers is closer to the target, and then to find the Unique ID to match.  The %closeness calculations are `(TARGET - LOW)/TARGET` and `(HIGH - TARGET)/TARGET)`, and subtracting one from the other gives you `2-(HIGH + LOW)/TARGET` - a Positive number means "High" is closer, a Negative number means that "Low" is closer, and 0 means they are both the same distance (I'll default this to the Low number).  We then use `SIGN` to change it to ±1, add 2 to get 1,2 or 3 and finish up with `CHOOSE` to output our number.  In pseudo-code, `CHOOSE(2+SIGN(2-(HIGH+LOW)/TARGET),LOW,LOW,HIGH)`, and the full thing:

```
CHOOSE(2+SIGN(2-(SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95)))+SUMPRODUCT(MIN($D$1:$D$6+1E+99*(--($D$1:$D$6<B1)+--($D$1:$D$6>(B1*1.05))))))/B1),SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95))),SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95))),SUMPRODUCT(MIN($D$1:$D$6+1E+99*(--($D$1:$D$6<B1)+--($D$1:$D$6>(B1*1.05))))))
```

Now, we have a number.  All we need to do is either use `VLOOKUP`, or use `MATCH` to get the row it is on, and `INDEX` to pull the data for that row:

Office 365:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$6,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(CHOOSE(2+SIGN(2-(MAXIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,">="&(B1*0.95))+MINIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,">="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&(B1*1.05)))/B1),MAXIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,">="&(B1*0.95)),MAXIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,">="&(B1*0.95)),MINIFS($D$1:$D$6,$D$1:$D$6,">="&B1,$D$1:$D$6,"<="&(B1*1.05))),$D$1:E$7,2,FALSE))
```

Otherwise:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$6,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(CHOOSE(2+SIGN(2-(SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95)))+SUMPRODUCT(MIN($D$1:$D$6+1E+99*(--($D$1:$D$6<B1)+--($D$1:$D$6>(B1*1.05))))))/B1),SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95))),SUMPRODUCT(MAX($D$1:$D$6*--($D$1:$D$6<=B1)*--($D$6>B1*0.95))),SUMPRODUCT(MIN($D$1:$D$6+1E+99*(--($D$1:$D$6<B1)+--($D$1:$D$6>(B1*1.05)))))),$D$1:E$7,2,FALSE))
```

(Obviously, change `$D$1:$D$6` and `$D$1:$E$6` to your actual data table ranges, and `B1` to the input-value range)